# Is this relation an equivalence relation? Check my solution please.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Define a relation R on the set {$2, 3, 4, ... $}, as follows.
$(x, y)$ ∈ R if and only if $x$ and $y$ have a common factor greater than $1$.

Is this relation reflexive? Is it symmetric? Is it transitive?

Is this an equivalence relation? Justify your arguments.

My Attempt:

1) It is reflexive, since the set begins at $2$ and $(x,x)$ will always be a common factor of itself, which is greater than $1$.

2)It is symmetric, because order doesn't matter. (I do not know how I should show this formally though)

3) Not transitive as $(2,6)$ and $(6,9)$ have GCF's $> 1$ but $(2,9)$ does not.

Therefore this is not an equivalence relation.

Comment: Your second sentence makes no sense.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz I meant that for this defined relation, it does not matter whether it is (2,4) or (4,2)... and I just do not know whether stating that is enough.

Comment: I meant the line containing „set of real numbers“.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz fixed.. sorry

Comment: The rest is fine. If you are unsure about (2) you can write something funny like “the common factors of $x$ and $y$ are the same as the common factors of $y$ and $x$”. Better not ;) Good thing is, if you are not explicitly asked to test all three conditions then it suffices to show that the relation is not transitive and hence not an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.
For symmetric, $(x, y) \in R \Rightarrow \gcd(x,y) > 1 \Rightarrow (y, x) \in R$